# How to Webpack setting can change require module path?

Tags: webpack

My test program looks like this-

```
script
 --app
 ---- member
 ---------index.js
 ---- util
 ---------memberKit.js
 ---- main.js
```

I want everywhere call `./app/*` to visit `script/app/*`

File **member/index.js** as follows-

```
import { show as kitShow } from './app/util/memberKit';
export const show = () => console.log('member show es6');
console.log(kitShow);
```

And file **webpack.config.js** as follows-

```
var path = require('path');
// var DirectoryNamedWebpackPlugin = require('directory-named-webpack-plugin');
module.exports = {
    devtool: 'source-map',
    entry: {
        main: path.join(__dirname, '/scripts/main.js')
    },
  // 输出的路径
    output: {
        path: path.join(__dirname, '/bundle'),
        filename: '[name].js'
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [{
            test: /\.js$/,
            exclude: /node_modules/,
            loader: 'babel',
            query: {
                presets: ['es2015']
            }
        }]
    },
    resolve: {
        root: path.resolve(__dirname, 'scripts')
        // plugins: [new DirectoryNamedWebpackPlugin()]
    }
};
```

My code results an error that as follows-

```
ERROR in ./scripts/app/member/index.js
Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve 'file' or 'directory' ./app/util/memberKit in /Users/xxx/Documents/temp/gulp-webpack/scripts/app/member
 @ ./scripts/app/member/index.js 8:17-48
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look into ways webpack supports module resolution. Specifically [this section](https://webpack.js.org/concepts/module-resolution/#module-paths).

Answer (score 0):

Your Webpack config is not correct (assuming using Webpack 2+). Also make sure that the config file is in the same folder as the `scripts/` directory.

What you need is:

```
resolve: {
    modules: [
        path.resolve(__dirname, 'scripts'),
        'node_modules'
    ]
}
```

Also, when you use Webpack's [resolve.modules](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/resolve/#resolve-modules) feature, you have to import those files as **absolute paths** not relative ones.

```
import { show as kitShow } from 'app/util/memberKit';
```

It might even be nicer to add the `app/` folder as the resolve alias:

```
resolve: {
    modules: [
        path.resolve(__dirname, 'scripts', 'app'),
        'node_modules'
    ]
}
```

So you can import things from their logical domain folders, and not worry about a folder called `app/`.

```
import { show as kitShow } from 'util/memberKit';
```